# Cannot view the properties window in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to develop a simple application Android Studio, where when i drag and drop any component from palette I'm not able to change the properties and view all the attributes.

It looks like the below image.

please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfLT9.png)

Comment: What is your question? I can't find anything wrong in your posted picture.

Comment: Can click the object itself in the left window instead of clicking the layout section? This should display the attributes of the editText component.